# Select a table from a different database without using dot (".")

Tags: mysql

I am searching for an alternative way to write mysqls `database.table` syntax. I tried to google it, but it is quite difficult to find out.

Basically I need a way to write

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
```

without the dot between `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `STATISTICS`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you want to use dots?

Comment: There's no way to do it. If you don't specify the database with a dot, it defaults to the current database.

Comment: Use information_schema; ???

Comment: @attila I am using an old https interface (no standard) to access a mysql database on a remote server from my server. However I found out, that it does not support dots in the query (Returns SQL-Errors). I thought that there could be a way without contacting the database owner. Thank you @Barmar - I think I need to contact the database owner now. @Stawberry I can not make use of the `use` command as my query seems to be executed by a php script. Thank you all!

Comment: are you saying you are passing it via URL? If so, then possibly escaping the dot with %2e.

Comment: I already tried this without success. Thanks @attila!

Comment: I'm guessing your PHP app is delimiting the `database.table` as if it's just an unqualified table name. So unless you can change the default database, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the command line you can specify a starting database:

```
% mysql --user=foo --password=bar --host=baz --database=information_schema -e "select * from statistics"
```

If you're already connected to a different database then do as @Strawberry suggests:

```
> use information_schema;
> select * from statistics;
```